# type error for value argument in yup test method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, validation, formik, yup

I am using yup for formik schema validation, I get an id number (string type) and check if it is valid or not with yup test method and an id number validator function
but I get this ts type error :

> Argument of type '(this: TestContext, value: string) => boolean | { status: boolean; message: string; nationalCode?: undefined; } | { status: boolean; message: string; nationalCode: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestFunction<string, AnyObject>'.
> Type 'boolean | { status: boolean; message: string; nationalCode?: undefined; } | { status: boolean; message: string; nationalCode: string; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean | void | ValidationError | Promise<boolean | ValidationError>'.
> Type '{ status: boolean; message: string; nationalCode?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean | void | ValidationError | Promise<boolean | ValidationError>'.
> Type '{ status: boolean; message: string; nationalCode?: undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ValidationError': value, errors, inner, namets(2345)

**here is the fromik and yup code:**

```
const formik = useFormik({
  enableReinitialize: true,
  initialValues: {
    idNumber,
  },
  validationSchema: ownerYup(idNumber),
  onSubmit: () => {},
});
```

```
export const ownerYup = (idNumber: string) =>
  yup.object().shape({
    idNumber: yup
      .string()
      .required("required")
      .test("nationalNumberValidation", "required", value => {
        else if (value && value.toString()?.length === 10) {
          if (idNumber === "") {
            return false;
          } else {
            const res = idNumberValidator(idNumber);
            return res;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }),
  });
```

**id number validator:**

```
export const idNumberValidator = (idNumber: string) => {
  if (!idNumber) {
    return {
      status: false,
      message: "invalid",
    };
  }
  if (idNumber.length === 12) {
    return {
      status: true,
      message: "invalid",
    };
  } else if (idNumber.length === 0) {
    return {
      status: false,
      message: "invalid",
    };
  } else {
    return {
      status: false,
      message: "invalid",
    };
  }
};
```

I tried to assign (value) "any" type but it didn't work as well